# Audio card in ubuntu 13.10 has lots of noise when a sound is being played

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, noise

It's not enjoyable to listen to music anymore, of course for me and everyone like me that has the same problem.

When I play a music it has lots of noise, the real track has no problem though.

This is the output of my sound info:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfe9f8000 irq 43
```

What should I do? Should I upgrade audio driver?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed VLC media player and it plays music in a way that you fall in love with music ;) .

The problem was rythmbox itself. I looked for changing something in settings dialog, but no success. I'd rather use VLC media player which is very powerful by the way and plays most of the music,video formats without installing further codecs.

Answer (score 0):

I would try going to audio settings and first mute the mic input. If there is still noise try changing your speaker setting from stereo to 5.1 or 7.1 (even if you only have two speakers).

Comment: Mic is off. where do you set stereo to 5.1 or 7.1

Comment: sound settings -> output -> mode ... you might have different options depending on your sound card, but you can try switching the mode and see if helps

Answer (score 0):

You should set all audio volume on the pc to 100%, and change the volume at the speakers.
At least don't run the pc at 20% and the speakers at 100%, for example.

Comment: Not true in my case.